# react-native run-android, Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I followed the intructions of [React Native Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html),  in the "Building Projects with Native Code" tab, for Windows and Android.

This is the content of the \AwesomeProject\android\build.gradle and after this there is the error I get when I execute: react-native run-android

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

When I execute: react-native run-android, I get the following error output:

```
D:\studio\study\reactnatv\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\studio\study\reactnatv\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (D:\studio\study\reactnatv\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (D:\studio\study\reactnatv\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)


D:\studio\study\reactnatv\AwesomeProject>
```

I checked this [US sanctions solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881165/react-native-run-android-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration) but it did not worked.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by my location. I had to use a tunnel for this. In that moment I created an SSH account here https://www.dynamicssh.com/create-ssh

1. With SSH credentials it is possible to set a local tunnel. I use Linux, so the tunnel can be set with this command.

   $ ssh -D 1337 -q -C -N youruser@yourserver.something

More details about it here: https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/

In Windows, I think it is possible to use a tool called Bitvise SSH.

2. Defined the variables **https_proxy** and **http_proxy** on the terminal for localhost:1337 (The port is the one you use to set the tunnel in the previous step.) This is to use the tunnel in the terminal.
3. Then run the "react-native run-android", in the same terminal where **https_proxy** and **http_proxy** were set.

Thank to all who answered.

Best regards.

Comment: Yeah, `dl.google.com` is blocked for some countries!

Comment: I am using VPN and I keep getting the error. Any specific proxi?

Comment: In that moment I think I used an account from here: https://www.dynamicssh.com/create-ssh Then I used those credentials to create a local port forwarding with a command similar to this: ssh -v -N -D localhost:1090 theuser@ssh-ipdyna-wathever.com With this you can setup http_proxy and https_proxy in the terminal. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain it. I am getting the same error for all my existing projects after I change their directory.

Comment: @IshaqKamran I have added more details of the solution. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 6):

You have to change this line at your project :

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I made the change you sugested, but I got a similar error: 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.

Comment: @eliastg you have to change the version as i stated, at your "build.gradle" file. Did you managed to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting all of your `node_modules` folders in the project and then rebuild.

I had this issue, and every time I would try to specify the gradle version it was requiring in my dependencies, I would get a separate error telling me that my gradle version was too low. This was due to some android libraries in `node_modules` requiring different gradle versions. Rebuilding `node_modules` from scratch should sync them up.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when my internet was turned off. Worth checking once.